# "Access to Keep is unauthorised" error message

Tags: google-keep

I started seeing this error message today whenever I open Google Keep. It reads, "Access to Keep is unauthorised".

So I have archived my notes and taken a screenshot to post here.

[image: Error message on opening Google Keep]

Can't find anything about this on Google. Any idea what this is?

OnePlus One, latest stock ROM, COS13, non-root. All apps updated to latest versions​.

And this issue seems to extend to the [Google Keep web app](https://keep.google.com/) also. Its says, "You’ve been signed out. Please reload the page to sign in again and continue working."

**UPDATE**

I no longer see the error message. It resolved somehow, and it's probably due to some work done from Google's server side.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue. Looks like it's happening to heaps of people

Comment: It seems to be resolved. I no longer see the error.

Comment: Yep it looks like it's resolved for me now, too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an outage on the Google side, see their [G Suite Apps dashboard](http://www.google.co.uk/appsstatus#v=status). Fix should be on the way.

The current outage (as of 11 April 2017) has [its own status page](http://www.google.co.uk/appsstatus#v=issue&sid=43&iid=b998aa8f87fce743bbb9cf6d24921534), and you can get details on future outages via the above dashboard link.

Comment: +1 Thanks for that link. But I'm not sure what it means. Is it resolved already? I started seeing the issue only today.

Comment: What timezone is the time you quoted?