# Google Keep keeps signing me out

Tags: google-keep

The following messages appear

> You’ve been signed out. Please reload the page to sign in again and continue working.
>
> Access to Keep is unauthorized.

Tried both browser and app, but did not work.
Only happen on one account.
Time happened: 06/07/2022.
Location: UTC+7.

Does my account get locked or is it a server-side problem?

Comment: Related issue (in 2017): ["Access to Keep is unauthorised" error message](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/172855/44325), but looks like there's no service disruption on the Google side at the moment.

Comment: I'm also on UTC+7, but I didn't face this issue at all. However, I'm afraid it's unlikely for us to know if your account is locked or not because we're not Google support.

Comment: This sounds like someone is signing your session out from account security controls.  Verify your account is secure, sign all other sessions out, change password, turn on 2FA, and verify no backup recovery method is insecure.

Comment: If it continues to occur, you may want to check that your emails and SMS are not being forwarded out, or if your mobile account has eSIM's/DIGITS provisioned without your knowledge.

Comment: It's fixed now i dont know what happen it's just occurs without  any  notification